# Apache or PHP Prepends HTTP Headers to CSS and JS Files

Tags: php, javascript, css, apache, centos

I am receiving odd issues with my JS and CSS files in my web application on my CentOS server running PHP 5.3.3. I have ran this application on XAMPP (PHP 5.3.1) and it does not do this. All my CSS styling and JS have the HTTP headers stamped prepended to them with some binary something in there.

What is going wrong with Apache? All these files are linked normally without PHP involved for the HTML documents.

Any help or ideas would be most appreciated! Thanks!

```
<T� �07�)�E����@�@���ߌM�ߍ��P��v�a�u6�v�����
H�e7,��HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Date: Wed, 15 Feb 2012 17:37:49 GMT
Server: Apache/2.2.15 (CentOS)
Last-Modified: Wed, 15 Feb 2012 16:36:01 GMT
ETag: "e0504-d02-4b9034e9521ec"
Accept-Ranges: bytes
Content-Length: 3330
Connection: close
Content-Type: text/css

/* GENERAL */

body {
font-family: Geneva, Verdana;
font-size: 10px;
color: #333333;
margin: 20px;
padding: 0;
background-color: #FFFFFF;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Run memtest86 to check if your machine's memory is faulty. Assuming you are using precompiled packages from your distribution it's unlikely that they are damaged in such a way so the most likely reason is a memory issue.

Comment: This is a KVM VM off an IT colleagues server, would it have memory issues like this?